# Numpy vectorization of multivariate normal

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2D numpy arrays A, B. I want to use scipy.stats.multivariate_normal to calculate the joint logpdf of each row in A, using each row in B as the covariance matrix. Is there some way of doing this without explicitly looping over rows? A straightforward application of scipy.stats.multivariate_normal to A and B does calculate the logpdf of each row in A (which is what I want), but uses the entire 2D array A as the covariance matrix which is not what I want (I need each row of B to create a different covariance matrix). I am looking for a solution that uses numpy vectorization and avoids explicitly looping over both arrays.

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(
                    cov=B).logpdf(A)`

Comment: I think you have to loop because the only alternative I can see is to pass in a 3D array (stack of covariance matrices). However, this results in the error *ValueError: Array 'cov' must be at most two-dimensional*.

Comment: 'numpy vectorization'  (avoiding explicit loops) is difficult if the `numpy` function (or `scipy`) doesn't work with higher dimensional inputs.

Comment: yes, thought so, just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4):

I was also trying to accomplish something similar. Here's my code which takes in three NxD matrices. Each row of `X` is a data point, each row of `means` is a mean vector, each row of `covariances` is the diagonal vector of a diagonal covariance matrix. The result is a length-N vector of log probabilities.

```
def vectorized_gaussian_logpdf(X, means, covariances):
    """
    Compute log N(x_i; mu_i, sigma_i) for each x_i, mu_i, sigma_i
    Args:
        X : shape (n, d)
            Data points
        means : shape (n, d)
            Mean vectors
        covariances : shape (n, d)
            Diagonal covariance matrices
    Returns:
        logpdfs : shape (n,)
            Log probabilities
    """
    _, d = X.shape
    constant = d * np.log(2 * np.pi)
    log_determinants = np.log(np.prod(covariances, axis=1))
    deviations = X - means
    inverses = 1 / covariances
    return -0.5 * (constant + log_determinants +
        np.sum(deviations * inverses * deviations, axis=1))
```

Note that this code only works for diagonal covariance matrices. In this special case, the mathematical definition below is simplified: Determinant becomes product over the elements, inverse becomes element-wise reciprocal, and matrix multiplication becomes element-wise multiplication.

[image: multivariate normal pdf]

A quick test for correctness and running time:

```
def test_vectorized_gaussian_logpdf():
    n = 128**2
    d = 64

    means = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (n, d))
    covariances = np.random.uniform(0, 2, (n, d))
    X = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (n, d))

    refs = []

    ref_start = time.time()
    for x, mean, covariance in zip(X, means, covariances):
        refs.append(scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf(x, mean, covariance))
    ref_time = time.time() - ref_start

    fast_start = time.time()
    results = vectorized_gaussian_logpdf(X, means, covariances)
    fast_time = time.time() - fast_start

    print("Reference time:", ref_time)
    print("Vectorized time:", fast_time)
    print("Speedup:", ref_time / fast_time)

    assert np.allclose(results, refs)
```

I get about 250x speedup. (And yes, my application requires me to calculate 16384 different Gaussians.)